# How to encrypt text between tcpclient and tcpserver in Indy?

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy10, tcpserver

I am using command like program between a tcpclient and tcpserver using Indy.

Is there a way to encrypt or something the commands sent between the client and the server ?

Comment: What's wrong with using SSL?

Comment: That encrypts the entire connection, which may or may not be desired. Maybe the user only needs to encrypt specific commands, or even just specific parameters. That level of encryption is outside the scope of Indy and should be handled in the user's code (though Indy could perform per-command encryption through of custom `Intercept`s.

Comment: @Remy: The poster says it's a *command-like program*, so presumably what passes between the client and server are commands. The question asks about *encrypt or something the commands*. What else might be transmitted that shouldn't be encrypted based on that information? And at the TCP level, all encryption is outside the scope of Indy, isn't it? It would all have to be in the user's code, whether it's via SSL or some other means, right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm lost, perhaps you can explain why security may not be desired?

Comment: Yes, of course there are ways. Can you please be more specific about what trouble you're having with the task?

Comment: @zaph: I did not say security is not desired. I said encrypting the *entire* connection may or may not be desired. The OP did not state clearly to what extent he wants to use encryption. Encrypt the entire connection, or just individual pieces of it that are sensitive. It depends on the particular protocol that the OP is implementing. For instance, encrypting the entire connection with SSL may be overkill if the OP really only needs something more like SASL to encrypt only sensitive command parameters but not the commands themselves.

Comment: at first I didn't care about securing the whole connection because actually I needed to encrypt only the login command with user and pass but ken white has a point if I can secure the whole connection why  not ..